# trigger popup message from asp menu item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, menu, popup

I have a menu in asp with many menuitems. 
I want one of the menu items to call a popup box.

I am using C# with code in a seperate file.

I would normally say something like:

```
RegisterStartupScript("Format Error", "<script>alert('Max Load Must be an Integer')</script>");
```

I want this to be called when I click the Menu Item.

The idea is that this can display an About Message box with like version in formation on it and other stuff...

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your menu static or dynamic?

Comment: I think that you need to go with Javascript only and forget the RegisterStartupScript for just one alert call.

Comment: static. Ill use javascript. I just don't know how...

Comment: I guess i have come a long way from my previous comment! I can't imagine trying to make a webpage without javascript now! What is C# code behind anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I have learned o so much over the past 6 months I can come back and answer my own question!

Answer: USE SOME FRIGGIN JQUERY! and it's so so easy!
[An animated dialog here!](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated)

You can say something like

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });
$("#myMenuItem).click(function() { $("#dialog").open()});
```

and have html:

```
<div id="dialog">all my dialog content here</div>
```

Hopefully someone will be able to use this! I check this site all the time, post a comment on this answer if you have a question an i'll explain further!

Wish I learned JQuery a long time ago...